# Handling multiple dynamic number of answers for a question

Tags: php

I have 2 tables, one for questions and the other for answers.
Each question could have 3-5 answers.

Questions table:

```
_________________
| id | question |
|____|__________|
|  1 |    q1    |
|____|__________|
```

Answers table:

```
__________________________________________
| id | answer | is_correct | question_id |
|____|________|____________|_____________|
|  1 |    a1  |     0      |      1      |
|____|________|____________|_____________|
|  2 |    a2  |     0      |      1      |
|____|________|____________|_____________|
|  3 |    a3  |     1      |      1      |
|____|________|____________|_____________|
```

On update page, I want to update both question and its answers.

The update form looks liek this:

```
<input type="text" name="question"/>
<input type="text" name="answer-1"/>
<input type="text" name="answer-2"/>
<input type="text" name="answer-3"/>
```

On page submit I'm trying to get the answers values and their ids.

I tried:

```
foreach($_POST as $input){
    if (strpos($input, 'answer-') !== false) {
            $answers[] = $input;
    }
}
```

But this way I'm getting the values only not the ids of these answers.

I also tried to give all the answers `name="answers[]"`. But it's the same thing I won't be able to get the answers ids.

Answer (score 2):

With the foreach loop syntax you can access the keys and the values of an array simultaneously, like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $inputName => $inputValue) {
    if (strpos($inputName, 'answer-') !== false) {
            $answers[] = $inputValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do the form like THIS:

```
<input type="text" name="answer[1]"/>
<input type="text" name="answer[2]"/>
<input type="text" name="answer[3]"/>
```

The php would look like this:

```
foreach($_POST['answer'] as $id => $answer) {
   // do the database instruction
}
```